# Who is the man with the sign in Episode 10 of Miss Monochrome?

Tags: miss-monochrome

In episode 10 of **Miss Monochrome**, about an android who wants to be an idol, Miss Monochrome decides to do a handshaking event like other idols are doing and it ends with a sequence starting with Silvester Stallone shaking her hand, which leads to an arm wrestling competition where she wins. In the audience was Mike Tyson, who sees her with approval, and it leads to a boxing match where she wins again.  In the audience was Hulk Hogan, who sees her with approval, and it leads to a wrestling match where she wins the belt. In the audience is this man, who also shows his approval, and it leads to a weightlifting competition, where she of course wins again.

Who is this man that leads to the weightlifting?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it's former [IOC President](http://gbtimes.com/world/tokyo-2020-olympics-political-albatross), Jacques Rogge.

[image: Jacques Rogge]

Comment: Yep, looks like him. I'd also like to add that right after the cut from the screenshot I posted, we saw the stadium (which was almost exactly like the picture from your link) http://cdn3.gbtimes.com/cdn/farfuture/zzbqb7rkrh1d-OyhGjDsu7dSrodJ8tELbuxqvJlI0mQ/mtime:1387207862/sites/default/files/styles/1280_wide/public/2013/09/10/tokyo-2020-main-stadium-conceptual_0.jpg?itok=ERjCSEWa